How to use children array in React
My intention here is to create a search component page, that has a form and a table, that can vary on fields and result.
Let's supose a component that receive a couple of children:
const SearchPage = ({title}) => {
    function handleSubmit() {...}
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form">
                {chindren[0]}
            </div>
            
            <div className="table">
                {children[1]}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

and now using this component:
const MyPage = () => {
    return (
        <SearchPage title="Search for fruits">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   <!--this is children[0]-->
                <input useSomethingFromSearchPageHere></input>
                ....
            </form>
            
            <table>                         <!--this is children[1]-->
                ....
            </table>
        </SearchPage>
    )
}

How access SearchPage variables and methods from children fragments?
This is the right way of doing this?

Consider using props rather than children. Relying on the order of children is brittle and will likely break

There's React.Children class with some static methods https://react.dev/reference/react/Children

@evolutionxbox, how?

To achieve your goal of accessing SearchPage variables and methods from its children components, you can utilize React's context system.
First, define a new context that will be used to pass the handleSubmit method and any other necessary data or methods.
import React, { createContext, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
// Create the context
const SearchPageContext = createContext();
// Custom hook to use the context
export const useSearchPage = () => useContext(SearchPageContext);

Update the SearchPage component to use the SearchPageContext.Provider to pass down the handleSubmit method and any other necessary state or functions.
const SearchPage = ({ title, children }) => {

 const handleSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
     // Your submit logic here
 }, []);

// The value object includes everything you want to expose to children
const value = { handleSubmit };

return (
    <SearchPageContext.Provider value={value}>
        <div>
            <div className="form">
                {children[0]}
            </div>
            
            <div className="table">
                {children[1]}
            </div>
        </div>
    </SearchPageContext.Provider>
  );
};

In your child components (e.g., the form inside MyPage), you can now use the useSearchPage hook to access handleSubmit and any other data or methods you’ve provided.
const MyPage = () => {
const { handleSubmit } = useSearchPage(); // Use the custom hook to access context

return (
    <SearchPage title="Search for fruits">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input placeholder="Search..." />
            {/* other form elements */}
        </form>
        
        <table>
            {/* table contents */}
        </table>
    </SearchPage>
 );
};


How about using props, i know this goes against question but it is the best way to do this. I also added types for clarity but please omit if not using typescript.
interface SearchPageProps {
  title: string;
  generateForm: (event: React.FormEvent) => React.ReactNode;
  table: React.ReactNode;
}

export const SearchPage: React.FC<SearchPageProps> = ({ title, form, table }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <div className="form">
        {generateForm(handleSubmit)}
      </div>

      <div className="table">
        {table}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <SearchPage
      title="Search Page"
      generateForm={(event) => <input useSomethingFromSearchPageHere></input>}
      table={<table></table>}
    />
  );
};



How "form" prop can access "handleSubmit" method?

1 min will refactor

how about the above? @Beetlejuice

I'm not sure where is the  definition in you example.
